# Starting multiple firefox instance in jMeter, some of them don't operate

Tags: jmeter, geckodriver

I start a load test for a web application with 25 threads in 60 seconds in 1 loop. The test consist of some selenium commands. When the test start jMeter start 25 Firefox windows but some Firefox windows do not execute the commands and remain blank.

---

2021-09-24 12:03:28,659 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione. (os error 10061)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'TESEO-TEST', ip: '192.168.80.52', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace:
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor58.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:140) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:99) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:22) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:234) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:784) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) [jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:752) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:740) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your system is capable of running 25 browsers?  Looking at [Firefox browser version 92 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/92.0/system-requirements/):

> **Recommended Hardware**
>
> - Pentium 4 or newer processor that supports SSE2
> - 512MB of RAM / 2GB of RAM for the 64-bit version

So do you have 51 GB of RAM an 26 CPU cores? It doesn't seem so as some of your browse instances don't respond to [JSONWire protocol commands](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)

Looking into [WebDriver Sampler Introduction](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#Introduction):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So you're supposed to be creating the main load using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and if you want to additionally test the frontend - use 1 or 2 browser instances. There are [several ways of converting Selenium scripts into JMeter test plans.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter)

Comment: My machine is a virtual machine with Xenon 14 1,80GHz processors and 32GB RAM. The CPU never go over 80% of load and the ram is occupied for the 30%.

Comment: However I cannot give up the use of Firefox (geckodriver)